# Model validation isUUID not working

Tags: sails.js

I am currently trying to implement usage of UUID as s primary key for my user model in SailsJS application, using MongoDB. As for now the primary key is generated by other system, I would like to validate if uuid attribute is valid UUID.

Validation *isEmail* is working fine for me, but *isUUID* accepts string like "john-doe" so it looks like it is not working.

My configuration looks like this:

```
    module.exports = {
        primaryKey: 'uuid',
        dontUseObjectIds: true,

        attributes: {
            uuid: {
                type: 'string',
                isUUID: true,
                columnName: '_id',
                required: true
            },

            ...
        }
    }
```

My only thought is that the validaiton does not work against primary key attribute.
Any ideas what else might be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code for creating the record ?

Comment: I am using autogenerated CRUD methods which are provided by Sails.